# Can't add days to Calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to write something that allows someone to check an audio book out for class, and it should set a due date for 14 days later. My class has a toString() method that should print out the due date, but consistently prints out that it is due 3/5 no matter what.

```
public String toString() // Prints specs of a Book object
{
    String str = "\nThe specs of this audiobook are: ";
    str += "\n\t Title: " + title;
    str += "\n\t Narrator: " + narrator;
    str += "\n\t Year: " + year;
    str += "\n\t Due Date: " + (getReturnDate().MONTH + 1) + "/" + getReturnDate().DATE;
    return str;
}
public Calendar getReturnDate() // Makes return date 14 days after today
{
    Calendar duedate = Calendar.getInstance();
    duedate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 14);
    return duedate;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
getReturnDate().MONTH
```

Isn't doing what you mean. Its value is the value of the `Calendar.MONTH` static constant, which is, I suppose, 2 (indeed, you can see it is [in the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#397)).

I think you mean

```
getReturnDate().get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

Additionally, you shouldn't be calling `getReturnDate()` twice: you might get inconsistent dates if you call it twice. Call it once, assign it to a field:

```
Calendar returnDate = getReturnDate();
// ...
str += "Due date " + (returnDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + returnDate.get(Calendar.DATE);
```

---

But in fact a better solution would be not to use these old, effectively-deprecated APIs.

Use a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html):

```
LocalDate returnDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(14);
```

Then access the `returnDate.getMonthValue()` and `returnDate.getDayOfMonth()` fields.

Comment: Thank you man, I would look in to using LocalDate but the assignment said we had to use Calendars.

Comment: What a lame assignment. Forcing people to use the outdated class instead of the modern and vastly better one.