# How to convert GregorianCalendar to Python / Jython datetime?

Tags: java, python, date, jython, gregorian-calendar

I'm programming in Jython and I would like to convert a java.util.GregorianCalendar datetime instance to a Jython datetime value.

I've tried this:

```
from java.util import Calendar, GregorianCalendar
import datetime

x = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()

y = datetime(x.YEAR, x.MONTH, x.DAY_OF_MONTH, x.HOUR_OF_DAY, x.MINUTE, x.SECOND, x.MILLISECOND)
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Then I ran this and I was surprised to see the wrong values written to the log. For instance, the year is suppposed to be 2020, but in the log it says "1".

```
from java.util import Calendar, GregorianCalendar
import datetime


x = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()

print x
print "Year", x.YEAR
print "Month",x.MONTH
print "Day", x.DAY_OF_MONTH
print "Hour", x.HOUR_OF_DAY
print "Minute", x.MINUTE
print "Second", x.SECOND
print "Millisecond", x.MILLISECOND
print x.getTime()
```

Log:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1591195394508,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2020,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=23,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_YEAR=155,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=43,SECOND=14,MILLISECOND=508,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
Year 1
Month 2
Day 5
Hour 11
Minute 12
Second 13
Millisecond 14
Wed Jun 03 16:43:14 CEST 2020
```

Could anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't add days to Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539049/cant-add-days-to-calendar)

Answer (score 1):

## `java.time.ZonedDateTime` replaced `GregorianCalendar`

FYI, you are using terrible date-time classes (`GregorianCalendar`) that are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Convert using new methods added to the old classes. [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) replaces `GregorianCalendar`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Proceed to extract the parts.

No need to add one to the month, as *java.time* uses sane month numbering, 1-12 for January-December. One of many reasons to use only *java.time*, never `GregorianCalendar`.

In Java syntax (I don’t know Jython):

```
int year = zdt.getYear() ; 
int month = zdt.getMonthValue() ;
int day = zdt.getDayOfMonth() ;
int hour = zdt.getHour() ;
int minute = zdt.getMinute() ;
int second = zdt.getSecond() ;
long micro = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMicros( zdt.getNano() ) ;  // Convert from the nanosecond resolution of java.time to the microsecond resolution of Jython datetime.
String timeZoneId = zdt.getZone().getId() ;
```

Two problems in the code seen in the Question:

- You use milliseconds, but the constructor for `datetime` takes microseconds. Here we convert the nanoseconds used in *java.time* to the microseconds used in Jython `datetime`.
- You neglected to pass the time zone to the constructor of `datetime`. Here we extract the ID of the time zone, a string in the format of `Continent/Region` such as `Europe/Paris` or `Pacific/Auckland`.

FYI, the legacy `Date` and `GregorianCalendar` classes have a resolution of milliseconds. The Jython `datetime` type resolves to microseconds. The *java.time* types use a resolution of nanoseconds.

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

That'll do it:

```
from java.util import Calendar, GregorianCalendar
import datetime


x = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()

print x
print "Year", x.get(Calendar.YEAR)
print "Month",x.get(Calendar.MONTH)
print "Day", x.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
print "Hour", x.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
print "Minute", x.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
print "Second", x.get(Calendar.SECOND)
print "Millisecond", x.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)

y = datetime.datetime(x.get(Calendar.YEAR), x.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,x.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), x.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), x.get(Calendar.MINUTE), x.get(Calendar.SECOND), x.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)*1000)

print y
print x.getTime()
```

Comment: Incorrect. You did not pass the time zone from the `GregorianCalendar` to the constructor of Jython `datetime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque You're right. I edited my response. The milliseconds are now multiplied by 1000. I still have to figure out how to transfer time zone information from GregorianCalendar to Jython datetime. I will look into that tomorrow maybe. For now, I'm happy with the result.

Comment: You shouldn’t be happy with that. `GregorianCalendar` is terrible. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community gave up on that class years ago with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and so should you. Consider using *java.time* as shown in my Answer.

Comment: I realize that, but I can't use java.time, because I'm developing an interface between two systems. System A sends date information as GregorianCalendar and System B expects this date information as python datetime. I do not have access to either system.

Comment: Easy to convert to/from `GregorianCalendar` and `ZonedDateTime`: [`GregorianCalendar.from( ZonedDateTime )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#from(java.time.ZonedDateTime)) and [`GregorianCalendar::toZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime()).